# pros/cons of keeping expired job content

Tags: seo

At the moment in my job site expired jobs redirect 301 to a deleted-page.

This prunes expired content and also causes less web clutter.

But I've seen many job sites keeping even old jobs which are in fact no use to visitor.

It is well known that it takes 2-3 years to rank well for a web page in Google. A job ad expiring in a month will have no page rank importance for Google and it does not know in advance that that page is going to be deleted very soon.

So which way should I go? Keeping expired content or deleting it promptly when it deems not useful anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep them just simple write a user friendly message i.e. Job has been closed. See here for related jobs. And if you are running some adsense then do it otherwise delete that page and redirect to the category page.

Comment: I like this solution, but any notice on the page must be very prominent (top of the page, big, eye catching) and come with useful actions like "see similar jobs", a list of similar open jobs, and "search for jobs".

Answer (score 1):

You should remove pages if they are not of any use for visitors. If visitors come to your page through Google search results and realize it is outdated, they just spend a few seconds on your site, maybe even disappointed with your brand/site and then go back to Google and search on.
I am pretty sure that Google is intelligent enough to figure which of their search results are useless for their users by tracking what they do after clicking a result.

Also, you should not 301 in that case. Only 301 if there is a real replacement for the content, the status actually says "the page content still exists, however it is somewhere else".

So, best bet in my opinion, for you, for Google and their users is: return a 410 status code to indicate that the page is permanently removed:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#410

> Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again.

Comment: Conside backlink juice as money, we shouldn't let it go by using a 410 on pointed pages. This i've concluded after reading many articles.

Comment: Some experts say this, some say that... Google aims to give their users a good experience, so IMHO it is the better not to pretend the content has moved to a page that has no relation to what the user has been looking for. Anyway, do people really say that many 301s to a single page keep the juice better than 410s? I doubt that. But well... who knows.